# awk command to print out entire row that contains a certain string

Tags: awk

```
output.txt
Test Results 1 PASSED with 2 minutes to process 0 issues
Test Results 2 PASSED with 10 minutes to process 0 issues
Test Results 3 FAILED ERROR 1 issues
Test Results 4 PASSED with 4 minutes to process 0 issues
Test Results 5 FAILED ERROR 3 issues
Test Results 6 PASSED with 19 minutes to process 0 issues
```

I need help coming up with a awk command to parse through this text. I want to list only rows that has more than 0 issue.

So in this case

`Test Results 1 PASSED with 2 minutes to process 0 issues
 Test Results 5 FAILED ERROR 3 issues`

Comment: Why would `Test Results 1 PASSED with 2 minutes to process 0 issues` be output since it has 0 issues and you want `to list only rows that has more than 0 issue`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$ awk '$(NF-1)' file
Test Results 3 FAILED 1 issues
Test Results 5 FAILED 3 issues
```

Comment: Can you please explain why does your solution work? (particularly with the use of `$(NF-1)`)

Comment: @MehdiCharife the awk man pages states what `NF` is so it's not obvious to me what part needs explanation. Where is it not clear?

Comment: @EdMorton The man page may explain what `NF` is, but there is a lot more going on in that little awk program than that. Breaking down why `$(NF-1)` works on this input would be good because while it's clever, it's not immediately obvious why it works.

Comment: @JM0 we can't explain awk fundamentals in every answer, at some point you've got to glance at the man page and think about it for a bit. You'll learn a lot more from doing that than being spoon-fed an explanation for every basic, trivial answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
awk '{if (($0 ~ /[0-9] issues/) && ($(NF-1) != "0")) {print $0}}' output.txt
```

Here the text is checked for number of issues.

It could have been done using

```
awk '{if ($0 ~ /[1-9] issues/) {print $0}}' output.txt
```

in case you are certain that there would be 1-9 issues only and not 10 or more. (regex would ignore 10, 20, 100 ... issues)